# The pump needle broke off, leaving the base in the nozzle. How to remove the stuck base?

Tags: pump

I was using this bicycle pump to inflate a ball. I inserted a needle pin to the nozzle, but the needle broke off after trying to insert it into the ball. The base of the needle pin is now stuck in the nozzle. What is the best way to remove the stuck base?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I just had this same thing happen last week. I straightened out a paper clip and bent a small hook in the end. Put the hook through the small hole in the center of the needle base and pull up. It came out pretty easily. Make sure you release the tension on the pump head first.

Comment: Noah Sutherlands advice about the torx bit worked. I didn’t even have to hammer it in to use it. I got the smallest one I had and put it down the middle and just slowly pulled it back out thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 3):

The "offcut" in the valve head is useless - so there's no point in trying to save it.  Your goal is to save the pump head.

Very first thing would be to make sure the lever is in the "loose" position.  It may be locked when vertical, or when parallel to the hose.  You need to remember which way is loose.

If you have access to left-hand drill bits or an easy-out then simply backing one of them into the valve hole might be enough to pop it free.  Another way to get purchase is to use a torx head driver of a suitable size, ranging from a t10 to a t20, and hammer it into the hole.  The lands on the torx driver can cut in to get extra grip.  It may destroy the torx bit.

You might choose to put some liquid penetrating oil into the head to loosen the threads, but this risks damaging the rubber components, like seals and gaskets and possibly the hose as well.  Perhaps this is a later option not a first line of attack.  Daniel's suggestion of liquid soap is great advice here too.

Your last resort is to replace the pump's head.  They can often be bought as upgrades from a reputable bike shop.

Comment: That head looks a lot like a couple I've had fail on me.  OK for cars up to ~35psi, but no use on bikes or even my van at twice that; the thin sheet-metal surround eventually deforms

Comment: @ChrisH yep - I suspect this pump is one of those car tyre foot pumps.  OP was asking about inflating sportsballs and it was a ball-needle adapter that broke.  Could even be off topic here.

Comment: Near enough though.  I have used such a pump for bikes (doubled barrelled; I had to push on the ceiling to get 100psi), and a valve needle with my track pump recently, so I'm inclined to think it's close enough.  I've also seen those valves on pumps sold in the cycling section of cheap shops.

Comment: Rather than penetrating oil, use a liquid soap.

Answer (score 2):

I turned on the air compressor and the stub was popped out, pushed by air pressure from behind.

Remember to undo the clamp lever.

Answer (score 2):

This just happened and I used a push pin to get under the broken needle and it came right out

Comment: Welcome to the site - noone else has mentioned using a pin so this a valid and useful answer.  Keep it up !

Answer (score 2):

The safety pin was a great suggestion. I used a thicker/larger one and placed it right into the middle of the broken needle. It had enough force to help me wiggle it out.

Answer (score 0):

I closed the pump like I was blowing up a tire and pumped air. It came right out!

Comment: What do you mean "closed the pump?"  Do you mean the latch on the nozzle?  Shouldn't that be open?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Exchange.  Could you elaborate a little more on your answer?  Acceptable answers on this and other Exchange sites should be complete. This is not a typical forum, it is a resource where appropriate questions are asked and well thought out answers are submitted.